# PhpStorm: Highlight Elementor Backbone Templates

Tags: javascript, wordpress, backbone.js, phpstorm, elementor

Is there a way to highlight Elementor Backbone templates in PhpStorm?

The code is gray and sad at the moment.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpStorm does not support code highlighting in the Elementor backbone template.
You can check out this [comment thread](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/8105) on the Elementors GitHub repository.